# data object different when loading JSON locally and on the server with coffeescript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

i use the following coffeescript to load a json

```
       $.ajax jsonPath,
        success  : (data, status, xhr) =>

            console.log("yea "+data)
            this.currentIndex = 0;
            this.imagesVO = data.images
            this.imageManager = new ImageManager(data.images)
            this.imagesCount = this.imagesVO.length
            this.switchToImage(this.currentIndex)

        error    : (xhr, status, err) ->
            $('#imageHolder').html("problem loading the json file, </br>make sure you are running this on your local server")
        complete : (xhr, status) ->
            #cconsole.log("comp")
```

the json is as such

```
 {
   "showName": "aaa", 
   "galleryName": "Season 3 Preview", 

   "images": [
    {
       "title": "Les goes shopping for a new car",
       "url": "images/hcp_stills-0.jpeg",  
       "description": "Sailboats on the Charles River" 
   }, 
   {
       "title": "Les goes shopping for a new car",
       "url": "images/hcp_stills-1.jpeg",    
       "description": "Sailboats on the Charles River" 
    },
   {
       "title": "Les goes shopping for a new car",
       "url": "images/hcp_stills-2.jpeg",   
       "description": "Sailboats on the Charles River" 
    }]
 }
```

when testing locally, i get the images array out of json like this, and it works
      this.imageManager = new ImageManager(data.images)

however when testing on the server, chrome complains that data.images is undefined, even thou the json is loaded in ok. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you expect json back.

```
    success  : (data, status, xhr) =>

        console.log("yea "+data)
        this.currentIndex = 0;
        this.imagesVO = data.images
        this.imageManager = new ImageManager(data.images)
        this.imagesCount = this.imagesVO.length
        this.switchToImage(this.currentIndex)

    dataType: "json"

    error    : (xhr, status, err) ->
```

If the server responds with the correct headers, it may detect that it is json and parse it for you, however it's safer to just go ahead and specify it.

Comment: how do i do that in coffeescript? when i add               $.ajax jsonPath,
   dataType: 'json' 
      success  : (data, status, xhr) =>

       console.log("yea "+data)